# Magical Record Truncate not working after app terminate

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

hey all i've code like this

```
if ([cellValue isEqualToString:@"Logout"])
    {

        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
        [EUserBrief MR_truncateAllInContext:localContext];
        [DownloadList MR_truncateAllInContext:localContext];    
    }
```

the code i want  to truncate all data on entities [EUserbrief] and [DownloadList].. the code working fine, but after app terminate and i get in , EuserBrief data and downloadlist still there,,,  any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
[localContext MR_save];
```

Your changes will not be persisted to any data store without saving.