# Truncate all with MagicalRecord not saving after app closes

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Magical Record, and what I want to do is when the user enters a multi item selector table view, he can check and uncheck many items, which, when done is pressed, are saved.

When I'm using the app there are no issue, but when I'm leaving and going back, all items that were checked before and the new ones are checked (let's say I checked 5 items at launch, then I go back in the multi item selector, uncheck them and check 5 others, the 10 will be checked when I'm going back in multi item selector after leaving the app).

Here is my code when pressing the "Done" button of my selector:

```
 -(void)selector:(KNMultiItemSelector *)selector didFinishSelectionWithItems:(NSArray *)selectedItems
{

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    currentFriends = selectedItems;
    

    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
       
        [FriendsSelected MR_truncateAll];
        
        for (KNSelectorItem * user in selectedItems) {

        FriendsSelected *friend = [FriendsSelected MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
        friend.friendID = user.selectValue;
        friend.friendName = user.displayValue;
        NSLog(@"Friend %@ Saved", friend.friendName);
  
        }
   
    }];

 }];

}
```

I tried saving when app terminate, I tried using completion and background tasks, nothing seams to work. Maybe I'm missing something ?

PS: I tried [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504080/magical-record-truncate-not-working-after-app-terminate) but it's not working, and MR_save is deprecated in the version I use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MR_truncateAllInContext:` to make sure your data is deleted using the context that is used for the actual save operation you're initiating with `saveWithBlock:`